# Uneven processor usage on a Multi core Postgre SQL server

Tags: linux, postgresql, cpu-usage

We have a dedicated server running Postgres 12 database with this configuration:

> Model: HPE ProLiant DL580 Gen9
> CPUs: 4*Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-4850 v3 @ 2.20GHz
> Ram: 128 GB
> Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
> Postgre SQL 12

The problem is that the CPU usage never reach 50%. When I checked ZABBIX logs found out when CPU usage becomes more than 40% `COU Softirq time` increases as you see:

[image]

When I checked PRTG Logs, saw something weird; The utilization of some CPUs are up to 80% but most of them are less than 20.

[image]

What's happenning here? How can I use all of my CPUs?

Answer (score 0):

You're describing one or two intensive queries. From experience Postgres will use multiple core's but each query is bound to a single core / thread (related I/O can be on other cores

Comment: Our queries are so fast. most of them are executing in less than 1s. And thre is not any other important services running on the server